# Spring-batch flow / split after a step

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-batch

I am building a spring-batch solution that contains the following process:

step 1 : split a list into multiple lists
 step 2 : process each sub-list
 step 3 : merge sub-lists

The generated sub-lists can be processed in parallel, and according to the spring-batch documentation this is supported. Sadly I can only find spring-batch example jobs that start with parallel steps, not examples that start out sequentially.

The following job will not compile. Spring gives me an error: 'cannot resolve step2'

```
<batch:job id="webServiceJob2">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2"></batch:step>
    <batch:split id="step2" next="step3"></batch:split>
    <batch:step id="step3"></batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

So how can I configure a job to first run a single step, than run a number of steps in parallel, and then run a last single step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've stumbled upon this question asking about how split works, and maybe this answer arrives a bit (one year) late, but here I go...

The issue there is "split" is not a step by itself, but you were naming (and referencing) it as it was:

```
<batch:job id="webServiceJob2">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2"></batch:step>
    <batch:split id="step2" next="step3"></batch:split> <!-- This is not a step -->
    <batch:step id="step3"></batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The correct syntax would be:

```
<batch:job id="webServiceJob2">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="split_step2"></batch:step>
    <batch:split id="split_step2" next="step3">
        <flow> 
             <step id="step2_A_1" ... next="step2_A_2"/>
             <step id="step2_A_2" ... />
        </flow>
        <flow> 
             <step id="step2_B_1" ... />
        </flow>
    </batch:split>
    <batch:step id="step3"></batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

But this is not what you want to achieve, because by `split` declarations you have to set in compile time the exact number of parallel steps that will be executed, and the purpose of split is using different steps in each flow instead calling several times the same one.

You should check the documentation about [Scaling and Parallel processes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning), the **partition step** seems a good candidate for your requirements.

Comment: In the correct syntax code block, where is the `step2` reference?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can have a split in the middle of a job! Here is the example from Spring Batch In Action (2012).

```
<batch:job id="importProductsJob">
  <batch:step id="decompress" next="readWrite">
    <batch:tasklet ref="decompressTasklet"/>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:split id="readWrite" next="moveProcessedFiles">
    <batch:flow>
      <batch:step id="readWriteBookProduct"/>
    </batch:flow>
    <batch:flow>
      <batch:step id="readWriteMobileProduct"/>
    </batch:flow>
  </batch:split>
  <batch:step id="moveProcessedFiles">
    <batch:tasklet ref="moveProcessedFilesTasklet" />
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallel steps would indicate a different step for each sub-list, which I don't think is what you want.
A single [Multi-threaded Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html) seems more appropriate.
As documented, you start by defining a `TaskExecutor` bean, which will process each *chunk* in a separate thread. Since TaskExecutors are fairly simple to use, you could also invoke the TaskExecutor on your own. In this case, your step can be multi-threaded without Spring Batch needing to know about it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not solve my issue. Each sub-list needs to be processed  by a different logic. (different read and process logic) I will take a look at the multi-threaded-step. For now I have solved my issue by simply using a switch statement in the read and process steps based on a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like below should hopefully help you:

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="step_0" next="split_1">
        <tasklet ref="taskletStep_4"/>
    </step>
    <split id="split_1" next="step_5" task-executor="taskExecutor"> 
        <flow>
            <step id="step_1" next="step_2">
                <tasklet ref="taskletStep_1"/>
            </step>
            <step id="step_2" next="step_3">
                <tasklet ref="taskletStep_2"/>
            </step>
            <step id="step_3">
                <tasklet ref="taskletStep_3"/>
            </step>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step_4">
                <tasklet ref="taskletStep_4"/>
            </step>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="step_5">
        <tasklet ref="taskletStep_5"/>
    </step>
</job>

<beans:bean id="taskletStep_1" class="com.test.batch.parallelstep.step.SimpleStep1" />
<beans:bean id="taskletStep_2" class="com.test.batch.parallelstep.step.SimpleStep2" />
<beans:bean id="taskletStep_3" class="com.test.batch.parallelstep.step.SimpleStep3" />
<beans:bean id="taskletStep_4" class="com.test.batch.parallelstep.step.SimpleStep4" />
<beans:bean id="taskletStep_5" class="com.test.batch.parallelstep.step.SimpleStep5" />

<beans:bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer could be improved