# How to have a Step and Split in single job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm working on a Spring batch.

In it, a Job should contain a Step(STEP_1) which must be executed as first step always and then there are three other steps that can be executed in parallel.

Without STEP_1 i can execute all three steps in parallel using the java configuration. But when I add this STEP_1 the parallel steps aren't executing. Can anyone show how its needs to be done using java configuration?

Attached a link where it was explained for XML based configuration. But I'm looking for Java Config.

[Spring-batch flow / split after a step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269091/spring-batch-flow-split-after-a-step)

Sample code :

```
@Bean
    public Flow splitStep() {
        Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>(step01().getName()).from(step01()).end();
        Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>(step02().getName()).from(step02()).end();
        Flow flow3 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>(step03().getName()).from(step03()).end();

        Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitStep")
                //.start(step_job_details()) // Single Separate step needed to be executed as first step always and then then the split steps.
                .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .add(flow1, flow2, flow3).build();
                //.add(flow1).build();

        return splitFlow;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The link is missing :"Attached a link where it was explained for XML based configuration"

Comment: Please share the code of the flow you have tried to achieve that.

Comment: Added the sample code and link